# OBS Installed, but unable to open it

Tags: software-installation

@A.B. This is the result of that command

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: What's "OBS"? Where did you get "OBS"? What do they say?

Comment: Start `obs` in a terminal, [edit] your question and add the output of the command.

Comment: The output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

Comment: This question should be opened again (I have an answer to post)

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem

```
error: X Error: GLXBadFBConfig error: Failed to create OpenGL context. error: Failed to create context! 
error: device_create (GL) failed
```

You need at least OpenGL 3.2. Therefore install a better or proprietary driver for your GPU.

Comment: It's an Intel, and according to the glxinfo output, Ironlake chipset, which means the hardware only supports OpenGL 2.1. There are no "better or proprietary" drivers to change that.

Comment: So what does this mean?

Comment: This mean, you can't use OBS.